# Using lombok with Spring

Tags: spring, lombok

I want to know if is possible to use `Lombok` with `Spring`, because in my project I got stack trace because I didn´t have a getter or setter method, but I put `@getter` and `@setter` annotations in my code.

```
@Data
public class EmailBean {

    @Getter @Setter
    private String contato;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String contatoCopia;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String copiaOculta;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String titulo;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String mensagem;

    @Getter @Setter
    private List<Contato> listaContatosSelecionados;
    @Getter @Setter
    private Set<String> setEmails;

    @Getter @Setter
    private boolean mostrar;

    @Getter @Setter
    private EmailHelper helper;
    @Getter @Setter
    private EmailFilter filter;

    public boolean mostrarListener() {
        this.mostrar = true;
        return this.mostrar;
    }
}
```

So anyone, can help me?

Comment: All your `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations are pretty pointless. It'd suffice to put them on the class. Moreover, `@Data` does it already. so remove them and give us the stack trace.

Comment: Do you use Lombok and AspectJ Compiler at the same time? -- I tryed Lombok with Spring and AspectJ once (End 2012) and noticed that Lombok with Spring was no problem, but Lombok with AspectJ and Eclipse does not worked very well.

Comment: @maaartinus I have other doubt, can I override for example a `setter`method? If I need to do some logic?

Comment: @Ralph I´m using Eclipse...

Doing what maaartinus told, it´s working.

Comment: Sure you can. If there's a setter already, lombok leaves it there (and you'd get a warning if nothing at all gets generated).

Comment: @maaartinus do I need to use any annotation to tell lombok to use my getter or setter? Where can I get more information about each annotation and properties?

Comment: In your example, all you need is `@Data`. Write a different class using the getters/setters to verify that they get generated. The javadoc should suffice, more information is on the [project page](http://projectlombok.org).

Comment: unfortunately I´m trying to use lombok also with my model classes but didn´t worked.

Comment: IIUYC this is rather fortunate (simpler to solve). It means that you didn't install it correctly. Did you started lombok.jar, did it find you installation and modified your eclipse.ini?

Comment: I did this. It´s working with other classes. But some model classes not.

Comment: @maaartinus problaby I discovered my problem, JSF objects has a problem with `@equals`, they need to be rewrite.

Comment: Disclosure: I am one of the code lombok developers. If you add your own equals and hascode, Lombok will not generate those. Who would need to rewrite? And what's the problem? Possibly you need to override canEqual, see http://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to override canEquals. See http://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html for more information.

Comment: does `equals` `hashCode` and `canEqual` methods will be generated if you don't ever use `@Data` and `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotations in the project code?

Comment: If you don't use any of the lombok annotations like `@Data`, `@Value` or `@EqualsAndHashCode`, lombok will not generate those methods.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, can you give code example? I add '@Data and \@EqualsAndHashCode to my class but I still get "No converter found for return value of type"

Comment: I also in anothe run added equals and hashCode functions that just return dummy values, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

So your `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations in there are redundant. `@Data` applies getters and setters to all fields in the class.